# Spring batch late binding for item reader, item writer and for Tasklet step

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using spring batch with boot.

I am getting the job id from `beforeJob` method from `JobExecutionListener`.  because of this spring late binding in readers and writers and tasklet step I am not getting my job id for my required reader, writer and tasklet files.

i need to append this `jobId` to my output files. ex : **outputFile_123**(my unique jobid) for all output files.

```
Listener.java: 
public class Listener implements JobExecutionListener
  { 
  public static long jobId;
  @Override 
  public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution)
   { 
      jobId = jobExecution.getJobId(); 
    } 


 JobId.java: 
  public static String fileName(String filename, long jobId) 
    { 
       return filename + '_' + jobId; 
     }
```

my writer will generate the output file:

```
writer.setResource(newFileSystemResource(JobId.fileName("filename"),Listener.jobId);
```

so this writer should written outputfile_123(unique jobid)
But this output file with jobId, I am not seeing in writer(ex: `FlatFileItemWriter`), and my reader(`FlatFileItemReader`) and also for Tasklet generated output files.
But in few files i am seeing the generated output files with jobId. for those files  i have written the code like below.

```
   File f =new File(JobId.fileName("filename"),Listener.jobId);
```

here I am getting that **outputfile_123** but not in the writer or Tasklet generated output files.

Comment: We need to see some code and the errors you are seeing to be able to help.

Comment: Hi Michale, thanks for your quick response. please have a look in to the below example code.

Comment: Listener.java:
public class Listener implements JobExecutionListener{
public static long jobId;

 @Override
 public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
  long jobId = jobExecution.getJobId();
        }
  
JobId.java:
public static String fileName(String filename, long jobId) {
  return filename + '_' + jobId;
}

Comment: Please edit: move example from comment to question

Comment: Hi Luca, I have moved my example from comment to question. please have a look.